# Trees in R: regression vs classification

Tags: r, tree, classification, regression

I am using the tree library in R, but when I fit the data into the tree command, sometimes I get a regression tree and sometimes a classification tree. What is this about? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the help page (`?tree`)

> The left-hand-side (response) should be either a numerical vector when
>   a regression tree will be fitted or a factor, when a classification
>   tree is produced.